# json.net Как сериализовать такой объект?

Tags: c#, json.net

json.net обычно сериализует словарь в коллекцию:

```
{"a":{"b":{"c":"d"}}}
```

Вот так:

```
class A
{
    public Dictionary<string,object> a{get; set;}
}

class C
{
    public string c{get; set;}
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.a = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        C c = new C();
        c.c = "d";
        a.a.Add("b", c);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Но я хочу сериализовать словарь в массив:

```
{"a":["b":{"c":"d"}]}
```

Есть ли простой способ сделать это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос "*Есть ли простой способ сделать это?*" - **нет**. Нет никаких легальных способов сделать это. Все потому что требуемый вами формат **невалиден**.

Вы можете только это сделать вручную, но вопрос уже будет в другом - *надо ли вам это?* Ведь никакой JSON парсер не сможет распарсить невалидную JSON-строку...

P.S проверить валидность JSON-строки можно на https://jsonlint.com/.